# Request SQL - Error Code 1052 Column in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1052

I have an error 1052 that I don't understand, how can I rectify it?
Thanks for your help ! :)

```
CREATE TABLE Commande (noCommande   INTEGER ,
dateCommande    DATE    NOT NULL,
noClient    INTEGER NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (noCommande),
FOREIGN KEY (noClient) REFERENCES Client(noClient)
);

CREATE TABLE Livraison (noLivraison INTEGER,
dateLivraison   DATE    NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (noLivraison)
);

CREATE TABLE DetailLivraison (noLivraison   INTEGER ,
noCommande  INTEGER,
noArticle   INTEGER,
quantiteLivree  INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (quantiteLivree > 0),
PRIMARY KEY (noLivraison, noCommande, noArticle), 
FOREIGN KEY (noLivraison) REFERENCES Livraison(noLivraison),
FOREIGN KEY (noCommande, noArticle) REFERENCES LigneCommande(noCommande, noArticle)
);

SELECT Livraison.noLivraison, livraison.dateLivraison,  
        detailLivraison.noCommande, detailLivraison.noArticle, 
        detailLivraison.quantiteLivree, Commande.noClient 
FROM detailLivraison
    INNER JOIN Livraison ON Livraison.noLivraison = detailLivraison.noLivraison
    INNER JOIN Commande ON Commande.noClient = detailLivraison.noClient
WHERE noLivraison = 105 
AND dateLivraison = STR_TO_DATE('09/07/2000', '%d/%m/%Y');
```

Comment: If you were to show us ALL the error message we would not have to guess which column is the issue

Comment: use the table name on `WHERE noLivraison` you have a column called this in at least 2 tables

Comment: And for all we know `AND dateLivraison` also

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: Or do a search for that error message before asking

Answer (score 0):

You have same column twice in your schema.

Try specifying the name of table you are referring to:

```
WHERE Livraison.noLivraison = 105
```

Comment: Do or Do Not, there is no "Try" padawan. A **good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: And we dont need any more dups please